# Принудительное завершение выполнения скрипта lua

Tags: lua

Нужно закончить выполнения скрипта при выполнении условия. Как это сделать?

```
if endOfScriptCondition then  
    -- Завершить работу скрипта  
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать [os.exit()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-os.exit):

```
if endOfScriptCondition then  
    os.exit(0)  
end
```

Comment: Стоит заметить, что `os.exit()` имеет два аргумента - код вовзрата (0 - всё хорошо, другое число - ошибка) и выполнять ли полную финализацию (`false` по умолчанию и на старых версиях, доступен с lua 5.2)

Comment: Из документации на 5.1: "os.exit ([code])
Вызывает функцию C exit, с опциональным параметром code, для останова выполнения программы-хозяина.", хе-хе. `return` или `error()` не работают что ли?

Comment: @FareakyGnome `return` - если не в функции только, `error` кто-то и перехватить может.